# Cannot install wine32 on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: apt, package-management, wine, dpkg, dependencies

I know there are a few similar questions, but I've been at this for a while and I think my situation is slightly different. I've already installed wine-stable, but wine32 will not install. I get this error message

> root@ubuntu:/home/parallels# apt-get install wine32
>   Reading package lists... Done
>   Building dependency tree
>   Reading state information... Done
>   Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
>   requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
>   distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
>   or been moved out of Incoming.
>   The following information may help to resolve the situation:
>
> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>    wine32:i386 : Depends: libwine:i386 (= 2.0.2-1~16.04.york0) but it is not going to be installed
>   E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

If i try fixing the dependency and installing libwine there is just a long chain of dependency issues. I tried using aptitude, but it suggested leaving lots of files uninstalled and it didnt fix dependencies. This is a clean install of ubuntu and wine, so I don't have the wrong version of files like the other asker did (his problem was resolved by downgrading some files).