# How to install the repository Wine package in 18.04 Bionic?

Tags: apt, wine, dependencies

I'm frustrated to utterly failed to install the repository verision of Wine in Ubuntu/Xubuntu 18.04 64bit. The version does not matter, but I want both parts i386 and amd64 installed. I continue to fail with the 32 bit part.

Here is what I did

```
sudo apt update
 sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
 sudo apt install --install-recommends wine-stable

 wine --version
    it looks like wine32 is missing, you should install it. 
    ....
 sudo apt install wine32
```

This gave unmet dependencies I could not resolve. Also aptitude could not. What is the correct installation process? Can you please give me a console log for a correct install?

PS: I am *not* looking for a winehq PPA install.

PS: I saw this post [Cannot install wine32 on Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/941066/cannot-install-wine32-on-ubuntu-16-04)

Comment: What is the hardware in question? You may want to add the output of `uname -i`.

Comment: @mikewhatever  Its pc hardware. uname -i  yielded x86_64. Does that influence the installation procedure?

Comment: No, I don't think so. The package `wine32` is in the Universe  repository, can you make sure it is enabled.

Comment: @mikewhatever Not sure what enabled means. apt-cache search lists the package. The repository has in the file wine/win24:3.0-1ubuntu1_i386.deb available

Comment: Enabled just means it is accessible. You need to solve those dependency problems. Might want to add the output to get help.

Comment: @mikewhatever Can you confirm that with those commands you managed to install a fully working Wine sofware from the Ubuntu repositories?

Comment: I don't have wine installed, but instead run a simulation `sudo apt-get install -s wine-stable`. There are no errors https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/bqKgXMfSmN/. ...didn't have to add i386 architecture.

Comment: Thank you that printout is very useful. May I suggest to post that as answer including your typed commands? I am going to re-install and try to confirm that.